# How to correctly implement trait for overlaping implementors?

Tags: rust

```
    pub trait DynConvert<T> {
        fn dyn__convert(&self) -> T;
    }
    
    impl<T, U: AsRef<T>> DynConvert<T> for U {
        fn dyn__convert(&self) -> &T {
            self.as_ref()
        }
    }
    
    impl<T, U: Into<T> + Clone> DynConvert<T> for U {
        fn dyn__convert(&self) -> &T {
            &(self.clone().into())
        }
    }

    struct A;
    impl AsRef<SomeType> for A {...}
    impl Into<SomeType> for A {...}
    struct B;
    impl Into<SomeType> for B {...}
```

There is this code. I have types T0..Tn and U0..Un that implements Into, and only U0..Un implements AsRef. How can I implement DynConvert for types that implement AsRef so that as_ref is called, and for types that implement Into, but not AsRef, so that clone and  into is called?

Comment: This question smells like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); I don't think you _want_ to have overlapping implementations, you _want_ convert from some types `T0..Tn` to some types `U0..Un` with the least amount of allocations (I assume)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just don't know English well, so it's a stupid question, but that's where you're wrong: Imagine that `T0..Tn` is struct `B`, and `U0..Un` is struct `A`. Imagine that there are many of these structures. But I want to convert to another type, to type `SomeType`. This type is meant as a generic parameter in DynConvert

Comment: Also note that the second impl will not compile; the value only lives within that method.

Comment: Please try to bring less hostility to a forum of people that volunteer to help you free of charge in their spare time.

Comment: I’m just Russian, it’s still logical

Comment: And in general it is not so useless. Teaching others is useful for yourself, and sometimes someone may stumble upon a question that is useful to them thanks to me

Comment: *"Teaching others is useful for yourself"* - yes, that's one of the reasons why I do it. But if everyone had your mentality, I most certainly would stop doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlapping impls are not currently possible.

There is an RFC that allows "Trait impl specialization" ([RFC #1210 "impl specialization"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), [Tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844))

Comment: So what should I do? Does this mean that Rust is not suitable for normal programming?

Comment: Use Rust idiomatically, which in your case means using `as_ref` if you need an (immutable) reference, or `into` if you need a (mutable) owned object. I'd recommend reading through https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/index.html first.

Comment: @Empty Just because the language doesn't work the way you want it to - and with good reason, mind you - and requires you to type a few extra letters, doesn't mean it's "not suitable for normal programming".

Comment: Too many letters needed. I need to either overwrite the crate I want to use, or create type wrappers, which is not direct access to the values. All this is not convenient. So, in addition to the wrapper, you need to make a macro that will create a huge bunch of code. And all because the language is not designed for a simpler and more expressive description of what I want to do. This rfc has been hanging since 2015. It looks like rust will die, and something else will take its place again, because rust is starting to sink into legacy like c++

Comment: It’s a pity to write code in Rust, realizing that later they will roll out an update that could reduce the amount and complexity of the code that should now be

Comment: *"realizing that later they will roll out an update that could reduce the amount and complexity of the code that should now be"* - that's how every programming language works.

Comment: Don't use it if you don't like it. Nobody forces you. If you don't understand Rusts advantages, it's probably not the right programming language for you. It's designed to overcome the frustration that people (like me) have with C&C++, and it does so very well, thanks to the borrow checker. If other things (like what you state here) are more important to you than that, then you are free not to choose Rust. And of course you are more than welcome to provide constructive criticism. I must wonder, though, if *"rust will die"* and *"sink into legacy"* still counts as constructive criticism, though.

Comment: But back to your question, trying not to get sucked into the hater pit: If both implementations were allowed and a type implemented all three `AsRef`, `Into` and `Clone`, which `impl` should the compiler take? Would you require the programmer to prioritize? This is a hard problem, so the Rust devs decided to disallow it for now and come back to it later. There are most certainly problems that could benefit from that, and I hit some myself already. But it's not an easy thing to implement, and there are almost always other design patterns that lead around that problem.